# Rounding problem with my result

Tags: sql-server

I have a rounding problem with the result of a query as shown below, where it feels that somewhere along the calculation the result was truncated. The result is

[image]

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT      
    "wos"."ISOVERDUE" AS "Broken SLA",
    (COUNT("wo"."WORKORDERID")) * 100 /(
       SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM   "WorkOrder" "wo"
       WHERE  wo.ISPARENT = '1'
              AND wo.CREATEDTIME >= < from_thismonth > 
              AND wo.CREATEDTIME <= < to_thismonth >
     ) AS "%"

FROM "WorkOrder" "wo"       
LEFT JOIN "ModeDefinition" "mdd" ON "wo"."MODEID"="mdd"."MODEID" 
LEFT JOIN "SDUser" "sdu" ON "wo"."REQUESTERID"="sdu"."USERID" 
LEFT JOIN "AaaUser" "aau" ON "sdu"."USERID"="aau"."USER_ID" 
LEFT JOIN "DepartmentDefinition" "dpt" ON "wo"."DEPTID"="dpt"."DEPTID" 
LEFT JOIN "WorkOrderStates" "wos" ON "wo"."WORKORDERID"="wos"."WORKORDERID" 
LEFT JOIN "CategoryDefinition" "cd" ON "wos"."CATEGORYID"="cd"."CATEGORYID" 
LEFT JOIN "WorkOrder_Queue" "woq" ON "wo"."WORKORDERID"="woq"."WORKORDERID" 
LEFT JOIN "QueueDefinition" "qd" ON "woq"."QUEUEID"="qd"."QUEUEID" 

WHERE   wo.ISPARENT='1' AND wo.CREATEDTIME >= <from_thismonth> AND wo.CREATEDTIME <= <to_thismonth>

GROUP BY "wos"."ISOVERDUE"
```

Comment: Try to convert to a decimal type  before  you divide. Data types involved are  `int` so, the result will be of this data type.

Comment: just change the `* 100` to `* 100.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COUNT() returns and [integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?#return-types). So both the numerator and denominator of the percentage calculation, as written in the question, are integers. As it says in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-types)

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

The solution is to cast one or other (or both) to a non-integer type. The [rules for precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) are a bit complicated so you may need to fiddle around to get just what you want. Or you can write a second CAST to deliver the percentage as desired.